# Creating Appropriate Arrow Next to Data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro through VBA code that detects whether or not a number is positive, negative or a dash (indicating zero), then inserts an up arrow next to a positive number, a down arrow next to a negative number and leaves the solo dashes alone, for a range of 20 cells in a single column.

The main issue I am running into is finding the best way to detect positive numbers for my code.

I cannot include screenshots or code excerpts due to confidentiality restrictions, but if anyone has an idea as the the code structure I would be very grateful.

Comment: The way that you detect if a number, `x`, is positive is to check if `x > 0`. You probably know that, so your question must involve something else. You should be able to mock up an example which illustrates your question without violating any confidentiality restrictions. Otherwise, your question is too vague to answer.

Comment: Also -- you might not need VBA for this, given an appropriate font choice for a column of cells (one that contains up and down arrows that you like) a simple worksheet formula which begins `=IF( ... ` can insert arrows or dashes in the columns next to them.

Comment: Conditional Formatting has Icon sets which include up/down arrows.